# How can I vertically center this "Content" div with TailwindCSS?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'd like to vertically center the div containing "Content" here using TailwindCSS and without resizing the width of the div:

```
<div class="flex h-screen min-h-full flex-col justify-center bg-gray-100">
  <header class="h-10 bg-blue-600 text-white">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl py-3 px-3 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="pr-16 sm:px-16 sm:text-center">
        <p class="font-small text-white"><span class="md:inline">Header.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main class="flex-grow place-content-center">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-6xl pb-10 lg:py-12 lg:px-8">
      <div class="space-y-6 sm:px-6 lg:col-span-12 lg:px-0">
        <div class="min-w-0 flex-1">
          <div class="shadow sm:overflow-hidden sm:rounded-md">
            <div class="bg-white px-4 py-6 sm:p-6">Content.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Here's an example of what this currently looks like: https://play.tailwindcss.com/whHEd0QsMB.

How can this div be vertically centered such that it doesn't change the width sizing behavior of the div?

Comment: Do you want to vertically center the div containing content or the content inside the div. If you want to center content in div use flex and center-items class.

Comment: The former not the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can add `flex flex-col` to the main element, and add `w-full` to it's direct descendant.

Here's an example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/kH7OIe6r8x

It seems that once `flex` is added to the parent container, the content element collapses because it has no minimum width and there isn't enough content in the example to force it's width to expand.

Comment: This indeed works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

TailwindCss works on the mobile-first design. Your style is mostly inspired from bootstrap.

Unsure about your experience with tailwindCss. I want to attempt to clearly convey the concept i have understood with my experience instead of just answering. Hope it helps.

As said above . Tailwind works on mobile first design, meaning any design you build is assumed to work on the mobile , and then for medium and larger devices appropriate tweeks are to be done.
So `px-4 md:px-6 lg:px-8` is preferred over `px-6 sm:px-4 lg:px-8` unless you want to be very specific with the design below `sm:` i.e mobile design

And if you are targetting design for devices of size between `sm` to `md` , you'll have to use `sm:` then.

Let's understand even further with the solution to the problem you are facing.

I have kept things simple. So that i concentrate more on the concept rather than just the code and for simplicity we'll consider we are focusing on just the mobile devices i.e anything less than `md:` and anything above the `md:` with different design.

The code goes like:

```
<div>
 <div className="flex h-screen flex-col bg-gray-100">
    <header className="text-white text-center bg-blue-600 m-4 md:m-2">
       Header
    </header>
    <main className="  flex flex-1 justify-center items-center">
      <div className="shadow bg-white rounded-md p-6 md:p-2 w-full text-center">
        Content
      </div>
    </main>
 </div>
</div>
```

**The code logic:**

- The entire display type is set to `flex` and made it `flex-col` because by default it is `flex-row`
- Inside which there are two items `header` and `main`
- And to align the just a `text` to the center we use `text-center`
- By default childrens of flex take just the height of its  child, so to give the `main` complete height we use `flex-1` property to fill the entire available in parent space.
- `justify-center` and `items-center` is to center all the children inside the `main` , in our case it is `Content`
- You can ignore the responsive design , i had put it to understand the tailwindcss's responsive design better.

**For medium size devices:**

- header with margin of m-2
- content with padding of p-2
  [image]

**For every devices less than medium size**

- header with margin of m-4
- content with padding of p-6
  [image]

Hope it helps !!

Comment: The example is based on TailwindUI, not Bootstrap. The media queries related to padding and margins aren’t really relevant to the question being asked. Your answer does not explain how to center the div (although based on the screenshot it might work).

Comment: I gave an insight of how the code is supposed to look , you want me to explain how the div is centred ? I can edit my answer. I guess the div being centred is self explanatory because of the minimal code written , let me know if any changes required , or if you are expecting a definite answer

Comment: I focused on the actual concept and actual best practices followed in tailwind and tried to explain the concept as in whole .., instead of just directly answering the question . Next time I'll try to keep it short and very relevant to the question asked . Thank you !

Comment: I just now added the code explanation, . I tried to precisely give a solution and explanation to the problem you were facing in the simple way, hope the edit helps. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can help you, cause you are giving h-screen in parent div which is related to header and main div & that's created complexity to make second div in middle.

However, use h-screen in main content div, which will set into middle according to your need. please check this snippets
https://play.tailwindcss.com/6M7jbrCZ78

```
   <div class="flex min-h-full flex-col bg-gray-200">
  <header class="h-10 bg-blue-600 text-white">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl py-3 px-3 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="pr-16 sm:px-16 sm:text-center">
        <p class="font-small text-white"><span class="md:inline">Header.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main class="flex h-screen w-full place-content-center items-center">
    <div class="mx-auto w-full max-w-6xl pb-10 lg:py-12 lg:px-8">
      <div class="space-y-6 sm:px-6 lg:col-span-12 lg:px-0">
        <div class="min-w-0 flex-1">
          <div class="shadow sm:overflow-hidden sm:rounded-md">
            <div class="bg-white px-4 py-6 sm:p-6">Content.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: In this version I have replaced the `h-screen` with `min-h-[calc(100vh-2.5rem)]` which helps take into account the header height.  https://play.tailwindcss.com/tZ0sD7mUL9